# Google Maps JS API - getBounds() not always defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps Javascript API to render a map and display a set of location markers on it. To reduce the amount of data being returned through the AJAX request that gets the locations I am sending the coordinates of the bounding box in the request to return only the visible locations.

I currently have code along the lines of:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Map.map, "bounds_changed", function() {
  Map.bounds.north = Map.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
  Map.bounds.east  = Map.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
  Map.bounds.south = Map.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
  Map.bounds.west  = Map.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
  });
```

Which as I understand how `getBounds` works should update `Map.bounds` (which is being sent to the server to retrieve the data) when the map is moved. However I cannot get it to set `Map.bounds` when the map is created, so the initial request for locations fails. If i call `Map.map.getBounds` outside of `google.maps.event.addListener` I get an error that `getBounds` is undefined. How can I set the bounds once the map has loaded, before the user interacts with it?

(I also tried `"idle"` in addition to `"bounds_changed"` with the same results)

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  The code you have posted shouldn't fail.

Comment: The code I posted does work, that was why I posted it, it's the only instance in which it works. Using the getBounds function in any other context gives an error that it's undefined (still inside the Google Maps callback however). I'm not so much asking for a correction to my code as an example of using getBounds outside of this exact case.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me.  An example of what you tried that didn't work, that you thought should have, would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Javascript API is event based. If you call getBounds on the map before the first `bounds_changed` event fires, it won't work.  Any time after it is set for the first time will work.

Example:

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 42,
      lng: -72
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" value="get bounds" onclick="document.getElementById('bounds').innerHTML = map.getBounds().toUrlValue(6);" />
<div id="bounds"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```